# Remove/unpair the ble device from the paired device list (smartphone)

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to unpair the ble device from the phone.

i.e. I can scan, connect the ble device. It´s OK! No news for now.
I know that there is the cancelConnection but this cancel the connection between  ble device-App (But the device is still in the paired device list in the smartphone).

I would like know if there is any way to remove/unpair the ble device from the smartphone.

Thanks!
Regards